# LimeSurvey mail contact info

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a question like the one shown in the picture below... How would I go about creating a label set where the boxes are next to each other and all under the same question

[image]

Comment: Do you have the URL for the form in your screen capture? If so, go to it and inspect it with say Chrome to figure out what HTML and CSS is used. The web is basically open source limited by your ability to decipher what is being done. To replicate a look, create a basic view with your form and then bring over their HTML and CSS piece by piece to both understand and get the same appearance.

Comment: @Cymen yes, it came from LimeSurvey http://design.limesurvey.org/prototype/question-library.php# they don't show how to do it

Comment: This question isn't actually all that bad (people were downvoting it). It just lacks some focus on the point that this is about LimeSurvey - which reduces it to a CSS question after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table.

Use floating CSS...

and many other options.

Comment: Thanks Neal, I'm familiar with how to do it with css floating div's but i'm trying to do it with LimeSurvey question survey builder.